# Does dropdown element support "required=true" attribute?

Tags: html

Does dropdown element support "required=true" attribute? I have a usecase where I want users to compulsorily select a dropdown option, but by default I don't not want to prompt any of the options.
If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does have required attribute. See below snapshot.

```html
<form>
   <select required="required">
     <option value="">None</option>
     <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
     <option value="Test2">Test1</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select